# Group URLs into single object output in API response

Tags: php, twitter

So I'll try to explain this as best as possible, but I'm having some issues with how the links are being rendered so I'll go into more detail below.

**Here is the full method**:

```
public function link_urls($text)
{
    if (!$urls = $this->get('entities', 'urls')) {
        return $text;
    }
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $text = str_replace(
            $url->url,
            '<a href="' . $url->url . '" target="_blank">' . $url->display_url . '</a>',
            $text
        );
    }

    return $text;
}
```

What this method does is it takes the `['text']` param response from the API and then it goes through and searches for URLs and appends HTML outputs.

---

Let's say that we have `$text` which outputs the following tweet data:

```
string(316) “As we continue to celebrate #BlackHistoryMonth , our next Black Artist Spotlight  is local painter @EbonyLewisArt https:// t.co/LaRa7GDk4i”
```

This particular tweet has 4 images, but Twitter groups them all into one "tweet" link as shown above.

---

Next, I'm checking the tweets `$urls` object that it returns, which is `$urls = $this->get('entities', 'urls')` which gives me:

```
object(stdClass)#1958 (5) {
  ["start"]=>
  int(115)
  ["end"]=>
  int(138)
  ["url"]=>
  string(23) "https:// t.co/LaRa7GDk4i"
  ["expanded_url"]=>
  string(65) "https://twitter.com/dallasmavs/status/1491079415375495168/photo/1"
  ["display_url"]=>
  string(26) "pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i"
}
object(stdClass)#1737 (5) {
  ["start"]=>
  int(115)
  ["end"]=>
  int(138)
  ["url"]=>
  string(23) "https:// t.co/LaRa7GDk4i"
  ["expanded_url"]=>
  string(65) "https://twitter.com/dallasmavs/status/1491079415375495168/photo/1"
  ["display_url"]=>
  string(26) "pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i"
}
object(stdClass)#1735 (5) {
  ["start"]=>
  int(115)
  ["end"]=>
  int(138)
  ["url"]=>
  string(23) "https:// t.co/LaRa7GDk4i"
  ["expanded_url"]=>
  string(65) "https://twitter.com/dallasmavs/status/1491079415375495168/photo/1"
  ["display_url"]=>
  string(26) "pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i"
}
object(stdClass)#1736 (5) {
  ["start"]=>
  int(115)
  ["end"]=>
  int(138)
  ["url"]=>
  string(23) "https:// t.co/LaRa7GDk4i"
  ["expanded_url"]=>
  string(65) "https://twitter.com/dallasmavs/status/1491079415375495168/photo/1"
  ["display_url"]=>
  string(26) "pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i"
}
```

---

**Here is the problem**:

I'm calling a foreach loop which grabs all the URLs and converts `$url->url` with an `<a>` tag and displaying the `$url->display_url` as shown below:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $text = str_replace(
        $url->url,
        '<a href="' . $url->url . '" target="_blank">' . $url->display_url . '</a>',
        $text
    );
}
```

The problem is that `$text` just has one URL to look on and the foreach loops through 4 times which causes issues and outputs the following:

> As we continue to celebrate #BlackHistoryMonth , our next Black Artist
> Spotlight  is local painter @EbonyLewisArt
> pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i”
> target=”_blank”>pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i”
> target=”_blank”>pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i”
> target=”_blank”>pic.twitter.com/LaRa7GDk4i

When I have one `$urls` object with one link in `$text` it's perfectly fine, the problem shows up when Twitter groups the links in `$text` and outputs multiple objects.

---

**Here are my questions**:

1. If there are multiple objects which are exactly the same, can I delete the other objects and just output one?
2. In the foreach, if the objects are the same, can I somehow skip all but one?

All help is appreciated on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change your `foreach` loop to this

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if( strpos($text, $url->url) !== false ){
        $text = str_replace(
            $url->url,
            '<a href="' . str_replace(' ', '', $url->url) . '" target="_blank">' . $url->display_url . '</a>',
            $text
        );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much @rudeboy21, answer has been accepted.